# How to avoid serializing null or empty fields into XML and still validate against a schema?

Tags: xml, serialization, null, xsd

I have a C# class with many properties which I fill in with information and then serialize the fields into an XML file, which then I want to validate against a XSD schema I created.

The core issue is that the XML file will contain information which can be retrieved from several different sources and it is very, very likely that several fields be null or empty. I don't want these fields to appears in the XML file, but the XSD schema is still expecting them to be there.

Given that many fields can turn out to be null, how can I avoid including empty field tags into the XML, while also being able to validate against a schema? What are the most conventional approaches?

Comment: If you create the schema and want elements (fields?) to be optional then use `minOccurs="0"`. If you want to use the XML schema convention of a null, it is `xsi:nil="true"` in the instance and `nillable="true"` in the schema. But that means you need to have the element/field in the XML instance and decorate it with `xsi:nil="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three possible approaches:

- Change your schema to match the instance document
- Change your instance document to match the schema
- Run the validation as a two-step process: first run an XSLT transformation to make the document valid against the schema, then run the validation on the transformed document